# Связь моделей Django через ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, foreign-key

Есть модели:

```
class AppointedDateTime(models.Model):
    appoint_datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.appoint_datetime)

class PersonalInformation(models.Model):
    pres_info = models.ForeignKey(AppointedDateTime, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name_guest = models.CharField(max_length =30)
    email_guest = models.EmailField()
    def __str__(self):
        self.x = str(self.name_guest) + ', ' + str(self.email_guest)
    return str(self.x)
```

Не могу понять как связать модели. Через админку все просто, но надо в ручную.
Например, в shell пишу:

>>>appoint = AppointedDateTime(appoint_datetime=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 14, hour=10))
>>>person=PersonalInformation(name_guest='Name11', email_guest="mail11@mm.com")

Какой командой их связать?

Comment: Все решилось.  a = AppointedDateTime.objects.get(pk=1)
p = PersonalInformation(pres_info=1, name_guest="Name2", email_guest="name2@bf.de")

Comment: `person = PersonalInformation(pres_info=appoint, name_guest='Name11', email_guest="mail11@mm.com")`

Answer (score 0):

```
appoint = AppointedDateTime(appoint_datetime=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 14, hour=10)) 
person=PersonalInformation(name_guest='Name11', email_guest="mail11@mm.com", pres_info=appoint)
```